# Find Primary SMTP address using Secondary E-mail address With EWS

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Using Exchange Web Services on Exchange Server 2010, I need to look up a user's primary SMTP address using a secondary e-mail address.

I'm trying to use ExchangeService.ResolveName(emailAddress). But, ResolveName() does not seem to match secondary e-mail addresses to primary ones. If I pass in the user's first and last name, then it finds the primary address. But, I need to be able to match using secondary e-mails.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I match a secondary address to a primary one?

Thank you,

Tedderz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.infinitec.de/post/2009/04/13/Resolving-the-primary-email-address-with-Exchange-WebServices-ResolveNames-operation.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call ResolveName with a string of the form `smtp:someone@example.com`. I'm not sure if ResolveName will ever return anything else than the primary SMTP address when called like this. But I checked the mailbox type just in case. The following code seems to work for me.

```
private string GetPrimarySmtpAddress(ExchangeService service, string email)
{
    foreach (NameResolution resolution in service.ResolveName("smtp:" + email))
    {
        if (resolution.Mailbox.MailboxType == MailboxType.Mailbox)
        {
            return resolution.Mailbox.Address;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Add error handling as needed of course.

Comment: Not strictly true, you can use other prefixes in calls to ResolveName, e.g. X500.